# Raise the minimum rep needed to create new tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation

Super User has a tag problem.

Due to many users who are not acquainted with the site barely reaching the rep threshold to create new tags, many such users misuse it, and that causes a problem as other new users just use such wrongly created tags. I thus propose that for this site only, the minimum rep needed to create new tags must be raised from 300 to 1000 or 1500, as on Math.SE and Stack Overflow respectively.

Quoting Jeff Atwood from https://meta.superuser.com/a/4116:

> I hear what you're saying -- on Stack Overflow we keep raising the amount of reputation required to create tags.
>
> I would rather do that than institute another "here is a dialog users will not read then rapidly click through" feature.
>
> Can you [...] create a new request, asking that **the amount of rep required to create a tag be increased on this site**?

(emphasis mine)

Quoting balpha on https://meta.superuser.com/a/591:

> I would assume that this is a problem with the amount of rep required
>   to create [tags], and less so about retagging. Do you have access to
>   statistics which of those tags where created during question posting
>   and which ones during retagging?
>
> Based on my assumption, **I'd rather suggest raising the "create tag"
>   rep border to 500**—I think that consistent, as you trust people to
>   "mess with the tags" either way, whether through retagging or through
>   tag creation.

Comment: Absolutely supported. Just from the latest newest tags added to the system I had to remove `[non-printable]`, `[insertion-loss]`, and `[delegation]`. People should understand that new tags they add don't help others find their question faster if those tags don't address any experts in a certain field.

Comment: I strongly support this and would want the limit to be as high as possible.

Comment: 10K? Sounds good to me

Comment: @CanadianLuke Maybe a little too much. I think that it should be 1500 like on [so].

Comment: Make it 10K. If someone with lower rep comes up with a good tag to add, there is always an option to discuss it on Meta.

Comment: 1.5k is fair. If someone's made it to 1.5 on a SE site as big as SU, they've obviously invested in the site.

Comment: Or just introduce a "request-tag" feature inline of asking/editing questions for users with 300 and above rep? Mods/10k/20k/trusted users will take a look at them. It will be a more universal gesture (I mean, StackExchange-Versal)

Comment: @AwalGarg And the 'creator' could have a shot at creating the tag wiki for the tag as well...?

Comment: @shub Excellent. That way, mod can see what the creator is aiming at... +1

Comment: @AwalGarg So you think that an inline feature should become its own review queue or should it post on Meta?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi No post on meta. So yes.... _own review queue_? :P

Answer (score 8):

Before doing this, I like to look at what might have been lost. The following 133 tags have been created by users with < 1500 reputation at the time of creation during the past 365 days and are currently in-use on at least 2 questions:

```
Name                     Used User                Created    RepOnCreation 
------------------------ ---- ------------------- ---------- ------------- 
sublime-text-3           90   Kriem               7/22/2013  404           
windows-8.1-upgrade      90   Joey Adams          10/19/2013 658           
sublime-text             42   Lohoris             9/13/2013  701           
chromecast               35   Raj More            10/4/2013  515           
ubuntu-13.10             33   Vladimir Oselsky    1/2/2014   332           
google-chrome-devtools   31   MoonSire            11/12/2013 442           
dos                      23   SofaKng             1/22/2014  327           
fedora-19                20   wullxz              9/11/2013  1217          
smime                    17   DeepSpace101        8/1/2013   538           
fedora-20                16   ChocoDeveloper      3/1/2014   739           
raspbian                 15   Bart van Heukelom   5/8/2014   882           
xfce4                    14   lang2               9/24/2013  436           
microsoft-surface-pro    13   Matt Clark          11/5/2013  304           
libvirt                  12   mavit               9/27/2013  310           
iis-8                    11   Feroc               8/14/2013  345           
xenserver                11   Alex                11/6/2013  339           
unresponsive             11   Mike Pateras        11/3/2013  356           
firefox-developer-tools  10   MoonSire            11/12/2013 444           
mariadb                  10   mickburkejnr        8/3/2013   730           
window-8                 10   curious_kid         12/28/2013 342           
remoteapp                9    damryfbfnetsi       1/14/2014  364           
downloading              9    broiyan             11/7/2013  357           
index                    8    Martin Prikryl      4/7/2014   932           
sfc                      7    galacticninja       12/29/2013 1423          
for-loop                 7    Kirstin             12/5/2013  1018          
cmake                    7    Chen Levy           8/13/2013  645           
font-smoothing           6    Robert Koritnik     9/3/2013   468           
tampermonkey             6    Brock Adams         2/6/2014   672           
pycharm                  6    Anthony Kong        2/26/2014  401           
traktor                  6    Franck Dernoncourt  4/6/2014   513           
search-indexing          6    Flak DiNenno        4/8/2014   594           
reference                5    Ian McClellan       3/12/2014  300           
mapped-drive             5    GSerg               3/27/2014  388           
beaglebone               5    Krumelur            4/1/2014   343           
hiren                    5    rossmcm             9/15/2013  391           
sata-to-usb              5    soul                9/29/2013  1314          
pgadmin3                 5    Eric Leschinski     8/10/2013  499           
whatsapp                 5    Antony Lee          8/4/2013   340           
sccm                     5    Myrddin Emrys       11/26/2013 1006          
internet-explorer-dev    5    MoonSire            11/12/2013 462           
html-mail                5    Camilo Martin       10/22/2013 619           
hangouts                 4    Ash                 10/16/2013 829           
bonding                  4    Nemoden             11/6/2013  356           
quod-libet               4    unor                11/21/2013 578           
windows-features         4    Brian Lacy          12/17/2013 746           
mpeg2                    4    Eli                 7/25/2013  431           
vb6                      4    nate                10/9/2013  492           
gridengine               4    gojira              10/10/2013 592           
windirstat               4    Josh R              9/10/2013  737           
fontforge                4    Eliptical View      1/20/2014  333           
cmder                    4    Zsolt Botykai       1/16/2014  399           
omnibox                  4    D.Iankov            4/16/2014  1471          
elementaryos             4    Deniz Zoeteman      4/28/2014  397           
oracle-linux             4    Simkill             5/8/2014   1224          
autologon                3    Colyn1337           4/28/2014  622           
parted                   3    wiak                5/2/2014   375           
superputty               3    Franck Dernoncourt  6/15/2014  691           
atlassian                3    Unnikrishnan        4/17/2014  601           
lftp                     3    wiak                4/16/2014  365           
displayfusion            3    Franck Dernoncourt  3/21/2014  493           
offlineimap              3    winchendonsprings   1/8/2014   457           
evil                     3    progo               1/16/2014  379           
opensuse-13.1            3    djechelon           2/7/2014   1275          
ffserver                 3    Yasser Zamani       2/9/2014   583           
lighttable               3    erikvold            2/26/2014  793           
zorin                    3    Zonder              3/6/2014   535           
freeradius               3    Augustus Francis    3/13/2014  370           
dax                      3    Andi Mohr           9/27/2013  342           
sparsefile               3    Michael Yasumoto    10/12/2013 385           
difftool                 3    Tiago Veloso        8/1/2013   897           
remmina                  3    Eric Leschinski     8/6/2013   474           
icedove                  3    l1zard              8/9/2013   508           
adobe-audition           3    Lynda               8/14/2013  1218          
shebang                  3    Ole Tange           8/21/2013  595           
clojure                  3    golimar             8/28/2013  515           
feature-regression       3    naxa                11/21/2013 1204          
adobe-creative-cloud     3    damryfbfnetsi       1/7/2014   302           
slate                    3    Duijf               12/1/2013  559           
config-files             3    thejh               12/4/2013  405           
apt-cache                3    Peter Westlake      10/30/2013 526           
badbios                  3    Ash                 11/4/2013  965           
radvd                    3    Dolda2000           10/20/2013 355           
mogrify                  2    wim                 10/23/2013 522           
mime-headers             2    Frank               10/28/2013 454           
rj-11                    2    Ash                 11/15/2013 1056          
elevated                 2    Langhard            12/5/2013  410           
jmeter                   2    TusharG             11/25/2013 695           
lotus                    2    Antony Lee          11/27/2013 540           
stylish                  2    Rookie              11/28/2013 363           
pkcs                     2    XXL                 11/28/2013 738           
lsusb                    2    Jonathon Reinhart   1/7/2014   478           
libusb                   2    Jonathon Reinhart   1/7/2014   478           
statsvn                  2    smokris             12/6/2013  434           
eraser                   2    oscilatingcretin    12/8/2013  876           
clearos                  2    NitroxDM            8/28/2013  341           
msklc                    2    Lohoris             8/20/2013  738           
iftop                    2    Eric Leschinski     8/11/2013  499           
elpa                     2    Chen Levy           8/13/2013  645           
awstats                  2    JoshRibs            10/13/2013 443           
psi                      2    unor                10/2/2013  559           
pipelining               2    Maxim V. Pavlov     10/4/2013  319           
tcpreplay                2    vpram86             9/26/2013  1105          
tarsnap                  2    Avery Chan          3/21/2014  753           
smb2                     2    Alexander Gladysh   3/12/2014  311           
ipkg                     2    Alexander Gladysh   3/12/2014  311           
udisks                   2    Envite              4/3/2014   350           
eap-mschapv2             2    Adambean            3/31/2014  496           
network-policy-server    2    Adambean            3/31/2014  496           
keyremap4macbook         2    Peeja               3/10/2014  346           
octopress                2    Anthony Kong        3/2/2014   406           
moinmoin                 2    lorenzog            2/26/2014  1106          
logcheck                 2    Eddie Parker        2/12/2014  331           
surface-2                2    Ben Johnson mk2     1/24/2014  640           
office-on-demand         2    damryfbfnetsi       1/28/2014  390           
sata-cable               2    Sickest             2/4/2014   742           
braces                   2    java.is.for.desktop 1/16/2014  435           
icicles                  2    Drew                1/16/2014  623           
terminal-multiplexer     2    shinokada           12/31/2013 307           
ssis                     2    Andi Mohr           1/15/2014  551           
sqoop                    2    P.Brian.Mackey      4/7/2014   679           
nconvert                 2    wiak                4/17/2014  365           
memory-speed             2    yosh m              4/9/2014   1133          
p2v                      2    user1301428         4/17/2014  1413          
answerfile               2    Colyn1337           4/28/2014  622           
noip                     2    einpoklum           5/9/2014   318           
msiexec                  2    Stefano Borini      6/6/2014   582           
system-notification-area 2    Edward Brey         6/7/2014   445           
texmaker                 2    Franck Dernoncourt  6/15/2014  703           
usbip                    2    davidbaumann        6/17/2014  873           
smart-tv                 2    PHPst               6/30/2014  554           
append                   2    nmuntz              7/2/2014   497           
centos-7                 2    Rob                 7/10/2014  373           
google-chrome-canary     2    Shimmy              5/6/2014   433
```

For contrast, users with >= 1500 reputation created the following 93 tags (again, only those in use on at least 2 questions):

```
Name                      Used User             Created    RepOnCreation 
------------------------- ---- ---------------- ---------- ------------- 
cmd.exe                   264  slhck            8/28/2013  62885         
onedrive                  199  tombull89        1/27/2014  4827          
windows-server-2012-r2    67   soandos          8/7/2013   14810         
hp-elitebook              65   DragonLord       7/27/2013  8319          
visual-studio-2013        57   Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007        9/20/2013  37956         
kali-linux                55   tapped-out       8/4/2013   2537          
ubuntu-14.04              51   Devid            3/31/2014  1906          
heartbleed                23   DragonLord       4/8/2014   10340         
email-filter              21   Breakthrough     7/1/2014   24324         
preview.app               18   slhck            8/24/2013  62426         
microsoft-powerpoint-2013 18   Paul             9/23/2013  22054         
textmate-2                16   slhck            8/28/2013  62909         
windows-8-refresh         16   Oliver Salzburg  3/19/2014  36867         
weechat                   14   tapped-out       9/2/2013   2709          
cutepdf                   14   wonea            9/24/2013  1579          
file-filter               14   Breakthrough     7/2/2014   24324         
windows-libraries         12   Darth Android    7/18/2013  19649         
lpt                       11   sammyg           8/4/2013   1690          
resharper                 11   wonea            9/25/2013  1585          
powershell-ise            10   Iszi             8/12/2013  3167          
citrix-receiver           10   wonea            9/7/2013   1528          
docker                    10   Oliver Salzburg  3/31/2014  37486         
gitlab                    10   Sathya           3/4/2014   35232         
bittorrent-sync           9    Ilari Kajaste    11/22/2013 1853          
footers                   9    WilliamKF        9/17/2013  1692          
bufferbloat               8    Kevin Panko      10/16/2013 2762          
miracast                  7    tombull89        9/27/2013  4630          
av-receiver               7    wonea            9/7/2013   1528          
powershell-4.0            7    Louis            11/23/2013 5583          
icalendar                 7    tapped-out       10/6/2013  2889          
intellisense              7    AthomSfere       10/10/2013 4782          
iperf                     7    sammyg           11/1/2013  2273          
windows-2012              7    PeanutsMonkey    3/11/2014  2034          
zabbix                    7    ekaj             1/8/2014   2151          
tuleap                    7    Sathya           5/28/2014  36008         
4k-resolution             6    WilliamKF        6/4/2014   2034          
tails                     6    Daniel Beck      5/1/2014   58204         
exchange-2013             6    ppumkin          4/3/2014   2341          
serial-number             6    netvope          1/5/2014   1501          
microsoft-access-2013     6    soandos          1/10/2014  15553         
tiles                     6    MatthewThepc     11/23/2013 2154          
static                    6    Ben Richards     12/6/2013  6504          
widi                      5    Pops             11/9/2013  3062          
rdiff-backup              5    davidgo          12/28/2013 7297          
mega                      5    wonea            9/15/2013  1552          
external-dvd              5    davidgo          8/17/2013  4678          
sequel-pro                5    slhck            10/3/2013  65843         
chocolatey                5    Julian Knight    5/29/2014  6010          
osx-yosemite              4    slhck            6/4/2014   78824         
tsv                       4    Indrek           4/15/2014  12291         
windows-embedded-8        4    Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007        9/30/2013  38495         
microsoft-excel-2000      4    wonea            9/26/2013  1585          
dia                       4    wonea            9/5/2013   1518          
steam-os                  4    Oliver Salzburg  12/14/2013 34329         
guid                      4    Synetech         12/20/2013 33862         
roles                     4    Keltari          12/2/2013  18089         
multiarch                 4    Vi.              12/5/2013  3842          
clink                     3    Charles Roper    12/5/2013  3844          
qmail                     3    Michael Kjörling 1/3/2014   6510          
melt                      3    slhck            1/10/2014  71506         
brackets                  3    Oliver Salzburg  3/19/2014  36867         
worm-media                3    Kevin Panko      2/20/2014  3405          
edible-ink-printing       3    rob              3/3/2014   8302          
digikam                   3    wonea            9/4/2013   1512          
adobe-bridge              3    tapped-out       8/31/2013  2682          
placeholder               3    Hennes           8/26/2013  24432         
carddav                   3    ridogi           8/27/2013  2185          
metasploit                3    wonea            9/24/2013  1579          
openscad                  3    Kevin Panko      10/24/2013 2784          
rsnapshot                 3    lajuette         10/28/2013 3274          
802.11ac                  3    Evan Carroll     5/24/2014  1523          
dm-crypt                  3    Gilles           6/13/2014  29685         
fusion-drive              3    slhck            6/25/2014  80066         
google-compute-engine     2    slhck            6/25/2014  80102         
zenoss                    2    Oliver Salzburg  6/19/2014  39519         
plex                      2    BigHomie         5/26/2014  2800          
can-bus                   2    evan.bovie       5/3/2014   2157          
magento                   2    Brian Knoblauch  5/6/2014   2877          
gdisk                     2    Mikhail          4/21/2014  2126          
rogue                     2    Keltari          4/2/2014   20865         
thrashing                 2    endolith         11/1/2013  1640          
windows-ics               2    tapped-out       10/6/2013  2889          
karma                     2    wonea            9/18/2013  1552          
pcoip                     2    Brian Knoblauch  8/15/2013  2702          
megui                     2    wonea            9/14/2013  1546          
personal-block-list       2    Al E.            2/8/2014   2454          
nexus-5                   2    Nathan Long      1/4/2014   3256          
block-device              2    davidgo          12/31/2013 7327          
multics                   2    Kevin Panko      12/4/2013  3028          
robots.txt                2    Nicu Zecheru     12/10/2013 2872          
hexchat                   2    Chipperyman      11/21/2013 1533          
faketime                  2    terdon           10/14/2013 18370         
ask-toolbar               2    ChrisF           11/24/2013 32141
```

During this same time period, 479 tags were destroyed, either because they were merged into another tag, weren't used on any questions, or because after 6 months they were only used on 1 question and had no tag wiki describing their intended use. It's not possible for me to determine who created them.

#### My recommendation:

Implementing this would be unwise at this time. Super User covers a large number of systems and products, many of which don't have tags. If we're going to further restrict the ability of folks to create new tags, those with the privilege need to be stepping up to create them when needed. Right now, that doesn't appear to be happening consistently: the majority of tags that end up being used more than once is done by users who would no longer be able to if we raised the privilege level.

Note that we [recently implemented warnings for new tag creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation/233897#233897) - whether this will serve to slow the creation of unneeded tags remains to be seen.

---

#### Appendix: tags removed during the past 365 days

Here is a full list of tags removed during the last 365 days, *for any reason*. There are a total of 703 of these tags, which reflects both a different time period from that above (I'm adding this information a month or so later) and an improved method of scraping the log files for this data (don't use SQL when you need a regex):

```
1.2.5
1password
2003
4g
4k
aafp
aalib
accent
access
access
access-denied
access-denied
ach-linux
activation
activebatch
active-window
actor
actors
adb
adfind
aero-shake
airprint
airprint
akmod
altgr
amd-raidxpert
amule
android-recovery
apache-2.4.6
apache-openoffice
apache-solr
apk
appcmd
appledouble
application-switching
app-switching
apu
archey
archicad
archivemail
areca
arrow
audio-port
auditing
autodesk-animator
autodesk-sketchbookpro
auto-hide
autopager
awesome
ayiya
backup-sqldatabase
bah
batch-processing
beep
belvedere
billing
bing-bot
bitlord
blackscreen
blocked
blurred
bomgar
books
boolean-operators
bottom-posting
braille
brands
break
brew
business-catalyst
business-model
cacti
caja
calc
call-forwarding
can
canadian-luke
capacity
carp
case-sensitive
catalina
category
ccsvchst.exe
cde
cell-phone
centreon
cfosspeed
chiliproject
chiliproject
chiliproject
chksk
chrome-app-shortcut
chrome-canary
chrome-url
cleanup
client
close-application
cloudflare
collapse
colorfultabs
comfort
command
communication
compi
computer-forensics
configuration
configure
conflicts
conve
conversation
copy.com
core-dump
core-pattern
cost-efficiency
couchbase
cpumon
cronolog
cstates
ctrlp-plugin
currency-conversion
current
custom
customization
cwd
d
das
data-destruction
data-formatting
date-range
daylight-savings-time
ddl
debian-7
dect
default
default-browser
defender
delegation
deleting
desktop-mode
desktop-window-manager
desperation
details
detect
developer
developer-tools
development-environment
device-id
devices
dicom
dictconv
diehard
different
digital-frame
disable
disconnected
disk
disk-erasure
disposal
disqus
distcc
div
dmake
document-library
dos
dotnetnuke
downtime
dragon-dictate
drbd
drobo-5n
dschychronize
dsquery
dualboot
dual-boot
duplicate-files
dust
dvd-flick
dxtory
dynamo
e-bay
economics
edge
edible-printing
editpad
education
electricity
electricity
elementaryos
elluminate
email-formats
emoji
emp
endianess
entertainment
epic
errors
eucalyptus
excel-2000
excel-2010-mac
excel-for-mac
exchangeonline
excle
exe
executable
expand
extension-cable
external-antenna
external-card
facetime
failure
fat
feedgnuplot
fignore
file-dialog
filesystem-limits
find-and-run-robot
fireworks
flickering
f-lock
flyout
focuswriter
font-color
fontforge
foot-bullet
formatted
forward-seek
foxit
france
freebsd-install
freeswan
freetype
frustration
fsnotify
full-computer-name
full-hd
full-path
fuser
fusion
future
game-server
gauthenticator
ghostview
gigabit
ginn
git-daemon
gitstack
git-tfs
gns3
goldwave
google-app-launcher
google-hangout
google-reader
google-ultron
google-wallet
google-webmaster-tools
gphoto
gpo
grainy
group-polcy
groupware
guide
guidelines
h265
hack
hack
hack
haiku-os
haiku-os-pm
hash-table
hash-value
hdf
headless-ubuntu
help-vampire
help-vampire
hidden
hide
hide-window
hipchat
home
horizontal
hotplugging
hpf370
hsqldb
html-editor
human-insensitive
hwnd
hyphenation
icall
idea
idl
idle
idm
ieee1284
ifttt
illustrator
imessage
index
indirect-reference
information
initcwnd
insensitive
insertion-fault
insertion-loss
inst
install4j
instruction-register
intel-mic
intel-vt
intel-xeon
intensifypro
intermittent
internet-explorer-desktop
invalid-ip
invisible
iphone-5
ipmi
ise
jdownloader
jetty
js
keys
kget
kids
kmscon
lang
laptop-displayblackscreen
ldme
ld-preload
leak
legalnoticetext
libopus
libtermcap
licencing
lilypond
lines
link2sd
link-shell-extention
liveticker
lmde
locked
lockup
logo
loop
loop
lte
lucene
lucidchart
lycom
mac-filter
mac-hg
magento
magic
maildrop
malicious
mapping
marquee
matching
maximize
mdsn
megui
memory-address-register
memory-buffer-register
memory-data-register
menubar
menus
metro
metro-twit
micosoft-word-2010
micro-receiver
micro-sd
microsof-access
microsoft-exchange
microsoft-kb
microsoft-office-365
microsoft-office-xp
microsoft-outlook-2000
microsoft-outlook-forms
microsoft-photo-editor
microsoft-word-mac2011
microsost-word-2011
middle-mouse-button
middle-mouse-button
minimal-install
minimize
minimize
minitool
missing-dll
mkfs.vfat
mktemp
mockup
modi
mru
mtools
mtputty
multiarch
name
named-formula
nbd
neorouter
net
netiquette
network-block-device
network-design
network-policy-serverb
nofiles
non-printable
ns3
nsswitch
ntds
nucleus-rtos
nuevi
numactl
nut
nvida
objectdock
offline
offline
old-hardware
omr
on-board-raid
oncenote
online
online-resources
open-file-dialog
openfine
opengrok
opensearch
open-with
operations
operator
oracle-11g
oraclelinux
osc
.ost
ost2pst
outlook-data
outlook-mac
output
override
p910nd
packa
padding
paintbrush
paperport
parentheses
parentheses
pattern
pbs
pci-dss
pdc
pdf-xchange-viewer
pelican
pelican
pendactyl
photography
photoshop-cc
photostream
php-fpm
physicalpath
pi
pinterest
pinterest
piping
plc
plot
plotting
plugings
pny
polish
portfolio
porting
poster-printing
povray
powerline
powerpint
power-saving-mode
preload
prices
primary-zone
printer-drivers
printer-sharing
product-comparison
product-number
program
program-counter-register
programming
protel
prototype
proxycap
psb
psreadline
.pst
pty
pydev
qubes
quicksearch
quit
r61
raspian
rawtherapee
rcirc
reader
reading-pane
receiver
recurring
reddit
redhat-6.2
rednotebook
re-encapsulation
reformat
refresh
refresh
reliance
reload
remi-repository
requests
request-tracker
resin
respawn
retext
rfid
rich-snippet
rpm-spec
rssi
rst
safari-6
safari-webinspector
sar
sar
sato-printer
sbcl
scattergraph
sche
school
scientific-linux-6
scilab
screenpresso
sd
sdd
secure
security-camera
self-healing
server
server
server-side
shares
sharing
shim
shopping
signature-verification
simple-mapi
simulink
simultaneous
single-bit-error
skydrive
skype-manager
smartart
smartos
smbios
smtp-client
snagit
snapper
snapping
soft-link
sound
sourcetree
span
spdy
spec
spin-down
sqla
sql-anywhere
sql-azure
sqltools
ssdt
stability
start
start-button
starter
stata
state
stereo-mix
stmp
stop
subject
sublime
sublime
support
surface
surface
surface-pro-2
symbop
sync-center
system
system-defaults
system-hang
system-load
t
tagging
tamil
targetprocess
team-explorer
technology
telepathy
teradata
term
tesla
tesseract
textmate2
texworks
tf
thinkapd
tiemu
tiling
timeclock
timesheets
tkinter
tonido
topology
tos
total-copy
total-eclipse
tracert
tracking-protection-list
transformer
transplant
troff
ttcp
ufd
uhd
ultimate-edition
umdh
umsdos
unicorn
uniform-server
unlink
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
untagged
userchrome.css
utility
v2p
vcf
verify
verizon-wireless
vertical
vgaswitcheroo
video-drivers
videowall
vigor
vigor2920vn
vintage
virtual
virus-scanning
virustotal
virutalbox
visudo
vp9
vswitch
warning
watts
where
whited00r
whmcs
winclone
window-8
window-maker
window-management
windows-2008-r2
windows-8.1.1
windows-phone-emulator
windows-service-packs
windowsspeechrecognition
windows-virtual-pc
windwos
win-key
wodim
word-2011
word-2013
wp-mobile
x1
x2go
xcos
xfsm
xmlsec
xnest
xpages
x-raid2
yahoo-search
yakuake
yammer
zarafa
zeitgeist
zend-framework
zombie
zotac
```

Comment: Those are shockingly good tags

Comment: I don't understand.  Most of the 54 tags that were created are not even used.  I don't believe a tag shouldn't be created for 1 or 2 questions.  I even see a few examples that should be changed, for instance `microsoft-surface-pro` is not basically a brand Microsoft has created, not just a single model of a tablet.

Comment: You don't like 2? What about 10? 50? The longer you wait, the more work *someone* has to do finding and retagging existing questions once the tag is created. Which, if you'll notice, mostly *isn't happening*. The most-used tag created in the last year was [tag:sublime-text-3] - and it had exactly *one* question in it when it was created on July 22nd, even though other questions had been previously asked about it. If you're gonna argue that fewer people should be able to create tags, then you gotta either have all the tags you need, or have folks willing to create them as-needed, @Ramhound.

Comment: This isn't the full list. I remember creating the tags [tag:remoteapp] and [tag:office-on-demand] recently. What about the tags that only contain one question each? And regarding the creation prompt, it does not describe what kind of tags are *not* permissible.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a hurry yesterday @damryfbfnetsi, and left out some of the details - see edit.

Comment: Ah, yes, but not all of the tags that were actually created that have more than two questions each are in that list. Like I said, I remember creating the tag [tag:remoteapp] before, but it is not in that list. And also, I've suggested edits to questions containing [tag:micosoft-word-2010] to remove the typo tag and replace it with the real tag.

Comment: w00t! You found a bug in my query, @damryfbfnetsi! Updated.

Comment: And like I also said, the tag creation prompt is inadequate. It does not say what kinds of tags we *don't* want, and it encourages users to just click the button without thinking.

Comment: Yeah, the warning is weak sauce - I'd prefer something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags) - but that'll have to wait.

Comment: Can you show us the ones created but later destroyed in the same range? (BTW, at least window-8 is a typo-ed tag)

Comment: See edit, @Braiam

Comment: @Shog9 Please ask the devs to make it possible to determine who created now-destroyed tags, as I think we prematurely destroyed those before their use propagated. This way the stats will be full-on and not just the good ones sifted out of the mix.

Comment: @Braiam There's somethings wrong with that new list. Some of them are duplicated (e.g. [tag:untagged]), and some of them were removed but were recreated and still exist today (e.g. [tag:microsoft-word-2011]).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi actually that's how Shog [pasted the list originally](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/8230/5), I only ordered them.

Comment: Duplicates indicate that a tag was removed multiple times, @damryfbfnetsi.

Comment: I think you should just try increasing the threshold to 1k or 1.5k temporarily to see what happens (whether the tag destroyal rate goes down/number of tag cleanup requests changes). We can revert it if it becomes a problem. I think so because in my opinion, the stats you have given don't adequately represent the full situation (because they don't represent removed tags), and because of the large amount of moderator and community support.

Comment: That never happens, @damryfbfnetsi. BTW, I'm not against raising the rep threshold - I'm against raising it *now*, when it seems there is much necessary retagging to be done. Make it your mission to make sure new tags are getting created when folks start asking questions about new topics, and get back to me in a month or so.

Comment: Revisiting this four years later. Can you please update the statistics?