# Do we need the tags [3g] [4g] [lte]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There is only one post with the tag [4g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/4g) and one for [lte](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lte).  Seems most of the questions tagged with [3g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3g) was related to mobile data applications - probably it is appropriate to merge these tags into one, say [mobile-data] or [3g/4g/lte].

Comment: It appears as though the post author is misusing the privilege to create a new tag...this is why we need to [give that privilege only to more trusted users](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8149/raise-the-minimum-rep-needed-to-create-new-tags).

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the tags [4g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/4g) and [lte](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lte), it seems there are no questions tagged with them, and so the tags will have been automatically deleted.

It may be a bit more of a problem with [3g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3g) because there are 145 questions so removing is not an option.

I think the best solution to this problem would be to merge them (like you said).

We will have to wait until a moderator or a high rep user can do this.